# Checking if an array is initialized and allocated in VB.NET

Tags: array, vb.net, extension-methods

I am creating an add-in for a piece of software our company uses, so I'm working pretty extensively with that program's API.  There are many COM object members which return or contain an array that I need to work with. Sometimes functions will return an uninitialized array (Null or "Nothing" return) or sometimes they may return an initialized array that is not allocated.  My goal is to eliminate redundant code in the form of `If`/`Else` blocks before using each array, or `Try`/`Catch` blocks to handle exceptions thrown by the array being un-initialized or un-allocated.

Note:  I'm not trying to *validate* any data here - that can be done in the calling code or in a function or whatever - I'm simply looking to determine if an array is in a usable state (e.g. initialized and allocated with at least one member)

I've created a member extension for arrays to check if the array is both initialized and allocated.

I'd like to get some input on whether or not this is a well designed solution or if it's total bupkis, if I'm missing anything else I should be checking for, and if improvements can be made in terms of robustness, efficiency, or general best practices; I would like to make it as fast as possible for dealing with large arrays.

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module Module1
#Region "Extension Methods"
    <Extension()> 
    Public Function IsAllocated(ByVal inArray As System.Array) As Boolean
        Dim FlagEx As Boolean = True
        Try
            If inArray Is Nothing Then
                FlagEx = False
            ElseIf inArray.Length <= 0 Then
                FlagEx = False
            ElseIf inArray(0) Is Nothing Then
                FlagEx = False
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            FlagEx = False
        End Try
        Return FlagEx
    End Function

#End Region
End Module
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **Option Strict**

  First thing first: **Enable `Option Strict`** please read : [whats-an-option-strict-and-explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454552/whats-an-option-strict-and-explicit)

  This will make your code less error prone. If you have enabled `Option Strict` you will see a warning on the line `ElseIf inArray(0) Is Nothing Then` that late binding is not allowed if using `Option Strict On`.

---

- **Regions**

  Please read [are-regions-an-antipattern-or-code-smell](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53086/are-regions-an-antipattern-or-code-smell)

  > Is there a good use for regions?
  >
  > No. There was a legacy use: generated code. Still, code generation
  >   tools just have to use partial classes instead. If C# has regions
  >   support, it's mostly because this legacy use, and because now that too
  >   many people used regions in their code, it would be impossible to
  >   remove them without breaking existent codebases.
  >
  > Think about it as about goto. The fact that the language or the IDE
  >   supports a feature doesn't mean that it should be used daily. StyleCop
  >   SA1124 rule is clear: you should not use regions. Never.

---

- **Hungarian notation**

  The parameter name `inArray` is a sign, that you are misusing the original intention. Please read this: [what-is-the-benefit-of-not-using-hungarian-notation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102689/what-is-the-benefit-of-not-using-hungarian-notation/102690#102690)

  And don't forget to read the reffered links.

---

That beeing said let us check how we could enhance this method by grouping the conditions together.

By using `OrElse` or `AndAlso`we can short circuit conditions, which means that if a conditionA is `true` the conditionB won't be evaluated. like

```
If conditionA OrElse conditionB Then  

End If
```

If we invert the conditions we can simplify the whole method to

```
Module Module2

    <Extension()>
    Public Function IsAllocated(ByVal inArray As System.Array) As Boolean

        Return Not ((inArray Is Nothing) OrElse (inArray.Length = 0) OrElse (inArray.GetValue(0) Is Nothing))

    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: Hmm... Idk about the Hungarian here. Seems more like a rare case of doing it right. And, as always, we disagree about regions in general. However, they're not needed here. ++

Comment: I use "in" and "out" prefixes for arguments identify arguments as inputs (provided with some value and evaluated by the function) vs outputs (provided as empty or null objects and populated by the function for use by the calling procedure).  I've advocated Hungarian notation in VB6/VBA, but in Visual Studio .Net it really seems unnecessary 99% of the time as the IDE does a great job of showing variable types.  BUT, there is no way (that I know of) in VB.Net to specify an argument as an input or output, as such the IDE cannot show you this info so I use hungarian to tell me.

Comment: It is not about the `in` but about the `Array`. If you change the type in the future but keep the parameter name the name is lying. A better name would be to call it just `input` then.

Comment: Gotcha - but seeing as this is an extension for the type System.Array, it's not very likely that I would change the type in the future ;)  However, your note makes sense and is well received!  ---  Also, with regards to Regions, this is totally new to me and seemed like a good way of keeping organized.  I can see how this could be considered an "anti-pattern" though after reviewing the link you provided.   I guess coming from VB6 regions just seem like a great new tool since you had a minimum of 6 lines for a basic Get/Set property wrapper!

Comment: About the regions I felt the same as I switched from VB6 to NET. Now I don't like nor use them anymore.

Comment: Last thing, with regards to `Option Strict` I have all these options set in the Compile tab of the project properties - is this not enough? Does it also need to be in each and every module (like it was in VB6)?  See screenshot of what I'm talking about [Here](http://i.imgur.com/eeHQHVL.png?1)

Comment: I'm following now Heslacher and if have to agree that the input type on a extension method is unlikely to change, but still, valid point. @CBRF23 setting it at the project level is a good call. You're good AFAIK.

Comment: @Heslacher - [Here is a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147057/option-strict-using-com-object-members-defined-as-base-types) you might be interested in regarding `Option Strict` on this application.

Comment: FWIW the MSDN does a pretty good job explaining how Option Strict On/Off works with the Compiler options.   >When an Option Strict Statement Is Not Present
If the source code does not contain an Option Strict statement, the Option strict setting on the Compile Page, Project Designer (Visual Basic) is used. The Compile Page has settings that provide additional control over the conditions that generate an error.
If you are using the command-line compiler, you can use the /optionstrict compiler option to specify a setting for Option Strict.

Comment: Sorry about the delay. Regarding Option Strict afeter I have seen the screenshots, my argument isn't valid anymore because you have Option Infer On which means that at runtime the right type will be used. It is like `Dim i = 1` where i will later be of type `. It is like the `var` keyword in C#.

Answer (score 3):

It's not bad. An extension method is a nice choice here. There's no state and you're extending a class that you don't own/can't directly modify. Good design decision. I also like that you're using the `Try...Catch` paradigm. A common mistake for VB6 devs moving to .Net is carrying over the VB6 *error* handling pattern.

One thing I don't like about what you've done is this.

> ```
> Catch ex As Exception
> ```

This catches every possible exception in the world, including potentially fatal memory errors. Be as specific as possible when catching exceptions. What specific exception would you expect to happen? Catch *that* instead, or none at all.

The only other thing I want to mention is that `FlagEx` is a poor name and the variable itself is kind of useless. Take advantage of the `Return` statement.

```
         Try
             If inArray Is Nothing Then
                 Return False
             ElseIf inArray.Length <= 0 Then
                 Return False
             ElseIf inArray(0) Is Nothing Then
                 Return False
             End If

         Catch ex As Exception
             Return False
         End Try

         Return True
```

Of course, you could take this a step further by doing away with the Elifs.

```
         Try
             If inArray Is Nothing Then Return False
             If inArray.Length <= 0 Then Return False
             If inArray(0) Is Nothing Then Return False

         Catch ex As Exception
             Return False
         End Try

         Return True
```

Which leads us to using some short circuiting.

```
         Try
             If inArray Is Nothing 
                 OrElse inArray.Length <= 0 
                 OrElse inArray(0) Is Nothing Then 

                 Return False
             End If

         Catch ex As Exception
             Return False
         End Try

         Return True
```

Then flip the condition so we can directly return.

```
         Try
             Return (inArray Is Not Nothing 
                 AndAlso inArray.Length > 0 
                 AndAlso inArray(0) Is Not Nothing)

         Catch ex As Exception
             Return False
         End Try
```

Comment: Thanks RubberDuck.  I just started playing in VB.Net so not really sure what exceptions to expect yet, hence the generic Catch for all exceptions.  I was planning to build more specific ones as I debug.  I don't know if that is good practice, but aside from experience I don't know how you would anticipate exceptions.

Comment: Okay, so what I'm going to recommend *may not be best practice*, but it has worked for me. Don't catch any exceptions at all until you find a bug. When an exception gets thrown that crashes your program, you've now added an exception to the list that *needs* to be caught and handled. Your mileage may vary. The docs are also a good source of information on what exceptions we might expect.

Comment: The reason I went with `elseIf` is because each condition needs to be checked in that order and if one is true, then we need to stop evaluating to not throw an exception.  e.g. if `inArray is Nothing=True` then trying to check `InArray.Length` will throw an exception because the array is uninitialized.  I'm afraid the `OrElse` and `AndAlso` examples will attempt to evaluate all conditions and result in an exception being thrown.  When you use the `Return` statement, does it also exit the function immediately? Because if so, then that seems a lot cleaner.

Comment: Yes. Return immediately exits the function. One of the beautiful additions to the language. Also, your fears about AndAlso & OrElse are misplaced. They short circuit. In other words, they only evaluate as far as they need to. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/817250

Comment: Awesome, thank you RubberDuck - very helpful link!  I did look at the MSDN article on [Return](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e34641s.aspx) but it didn't explicitly state that it also exits the function - though the sample code makes it appear so.  Also great to know that logical operators short-circuit - I will remember that for future designs!  Excellent, excellent feedback!